# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75 but I do have chromedriver 75 (webdriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

ubuntu 18.04 just started getting this when using webdriver through ruby (ruby v2.4.0).

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75

but

`$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8
(681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40})`

This is happening with both the `chromedriver-helper` gem (deprecated) and the replacement `webdrivers` gem both of which show they are `Using selenium-webdriver 2.53.3`

Moving up Ruby version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 gave a different error:

```
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from app.rb:71:in `<main>'
    10: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:223:in `visit'
     9: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in `visit'
     8: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
     7: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
     6: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:64:in `for'
     5: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:64:in `new'
     4: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:34:in `initialize'
     3: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:67:in `start'
     2: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:43:in `locked'
     1: from /home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:70:in `block in start'
/home/michael/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:115:in `connect_until_stable': unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

Trying ruby 2.6.2 gave a different error

session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)

even though

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 
(681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40})
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: *did not work on another machine with ruby 2.6.2  I don't know why yet*

Not a good answer as it doesn't fix the problem, but:

> with with a newer version of ruby - 2.6.2 the browser works correctly.

So for now at least 2.6.2 works. (actually my capybara form filling stop working but I will look into that separately)

I've encountered other problems with Ruby 2.6.2 not being available in all places but that will probably change soon.